# Assigning a keyboard key as a shortcut to another key combo

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

Is it possible in Windows to hijack say the <kbd>F3</kbd> key to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>? Or the tab key to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (not that I'd re-purpose tab, but just as an example). I don't mind installing a third party utility if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) from Microsoft. One of the toys Keyboard Manager is made just for what you are looking for:

> Keyboard Manager allows you to customize the keyboard to be more productive by remapping keys and creating your own keyboard shortcuts. This PowerToy requires Windows 10 1903 (build 18362) or later.

To use it, go to the PowerToys settings, select Keyboard Manager, then click Remap Key.
[image]

Select the key that should be remapped plus the key that should take its place. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. That's it.

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect - both really nice solutions but this method is has a user-friendly GUI and it's official Microsoft too.

Comment: Just what I needed. I don't have an insert key on my keyboard, now I can shift-insert from bash !

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a scripting language named AutoHotKey for creating custom hotkeys and remapping one keys to another. You can find tutorial and documentation in their [official website](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Comment: Thanks, this looks ideal!